# Non Homogenous Poisson Process in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, poisson

I am trying to simulate the Mt/M/c queueing model in Anylogic. I want the Source to generate agent by a Non Homogenous Poisson Process, which requires the arrival rate function to be like, for example, a+b*sin(t). However, I found that the source can only generate by fixed rate or rate schedule.

I am wondering if there is some way to generate agents by the rate function given in Anylogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, set the Source to "create agents by call of inject()" method:
[image]

Then, create a DynamicEvent with the action code as below. This will inject 1 agent at the specified interval from your equation:
[image]

Last, you need to "seed" this setup by calling `create_MyDynamicEvent(0, SECOND)` once on startup of Main (to make the dynamic event re-call itself from then onwards)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think in this way it may not be a non homogeneous poisson process, since every arrival interval is fixed once the first arrival is generated, while the non homogeneous poisson process has stochastic intervals. But thanks to your answer, I think that  using the DynamicEvent block  and changing a little bit about your timeToNextEvent variable by adding some random() function can solve the problem.

Comment: The function can be like random.exponential(a*t+bsin(t)-a*t'-bsin(t')) in python. I'll complete the rest later.

Comment: Sure, this is just to get you started. Feel free to ask a separate follow-up question if you get stuck again :)